# c# , Mysql data comparison issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I am using mysql with asp.net to save data in DB . When I save data in DB after using server.HTMLEncode(), the data is saved after removing \ . This is how I am saving data

```
INSERT INTO Users(ID,Name) Values(1,Server.HTMLEncode(User.Identity.Name))
```

In this case if name is XXX\ABC , it is being saved as XXXABC. Slashes are removed while saving in DB.

Next time when I read the same , I need to check if logged in user is the one against whom I saved data so I do following

```
if ( existingRowEditor == Server.HtmlEncode(User.Identity.Name))
{

}
```

but the issue is that the above condition is always false because I have following values 
`existingRowEditor="XXXABC"` and `Server.HtmlEncode(User.Identity.Name) =XXX\\ABC`.

So how can I check if the above condition is true?

Comment: Why are you HTML-encoding the user name?

Comment: even if I do not HTMLEncode the name , it still saves XXXABC in DB i.e. removes the \\ from name

Comment: The "code" you've given for how you're saving data is very strange - it's a mixture of C# and SQL. Please show what the code *actually* looks like. If you're not using parameterized SQL, that could very easily be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML encoding is not suitable for encoding data for storage in the database.

The reason that the backslashes disappears is that you are pasting together SQL code, and encoding the text for display in the web page instead of escaping it for being text in an SQL query. The backslash is used as escape character in MySQL, so any bacslashes in the string will escape the next character.

Preferrably you should use parameterised queries instead of concatenating the data into the SQL query. If that is not possible, you *must* escape the text properly to be in a string literal in SQL code, so you have to replace every backslash with double backsashes, and prepend every apostrophe with a backslash. If you fail to escape it properly, you application will be wide open for SQL injection attacks.

HTML encoding values should be done when you display it in a web page, not before you put it in the datbase.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
var sqlQueryString = "INSERT INTO Users(ID,Name) Values(@Id,@Name)";
var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQueryString, sqlConnection);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Id", 1);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", User.Identity.Name);
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```